Odoo16: api.depends call order
In Odoo 16, I have 2 computed fields:
rec_name = fields.Char('Rec name', compute='_compute_rec_name', store=True, translate=True)
located_between = fields.Char('Located between', compute='_compute_located_between', store=True)

And the 2 functions of theses fields are:
@api.depends('name', 'line_type', 'located_between')
def _compute_rec_name(self):
    for rec in self:
        print("Rec name")
        if rec.name:
            rec.rec_name = rec.name
        else:
            line_type_string = dict(rec._fields['line_type']._description_selection(self.env)).get(rec.line_type)
            rec.rec_name = _('%s between %s', line_type_string, rec.located_between)

@api.depends('sequence')
def _compute_located_between(self):
    for rec in self:
        print("Located between")
        if not rec.activable:
            all_previous_activable_line = self.search([('track_table_id', '=', rec.track_table_id.id), ('activable', '=', True), ('sequence', '<', rec.sequence)])
            all_next_activable_line = self.search([('track_table_id', '=', rec.track_table_id.id), ('activable', '=', True), ('sequence', '>', rec.sequence)])
            if len(all_previous_activable_line) > 0 and len(all_next_activable_line) > 0:
                rec.located_between = _('%s and %s', all_previous_activable_line[-1].name, all_next_activable_line[0].name)
            else:
                rec.located_between = _('No activable line before or after this one')
        else:
            rec.located_between = ''

The problem is that the _compute_rec_name function is called before _compute_located_between (check with print) and the result is false because _compute_rec_name take old value of located_between instead of newest.
I tried:

to remove the dependencies of located_between for the function _compute_rec_name and the function isn't called as expected.
to put _compute_rec_name after _compute_located_between in the code but it doesn't work

Is there any way to change the order of execution?

I'm guessing it's due to the trigger fields (the ap.depends parameter) on each method, maybe the field sequence does not change first so _compute_located_between is not triggered.
Have you considered computing those two fields in one method? something like
rec_name = fields.Char('Rec name', compute='_compute_name_loc', store=True, translate=True)
located_between = fields.Char('Located between', compute='_compute_name_loc', store=True)

@api.depends(''name', 'line_type', 'sequence')    
def _compute_name_loc(self):
    for rec in self:
        # code for located_between field
        if not rec.activable:
            all_previous_activable_line = self.search([('track_table_id', '=', rec.track_table_id.id), ('activable', '=', True), ('sequence', '<', rec.sequence)])
            all_next_activable_line = self.search([('track_table_id', '=', rec.track_table_id.id), ('activable', '=', True), ('sequence', '>', rec.sequence)])
            if len(all_previous_activable_line) > 0 and len(all_next_activable_line) > 0:
                rec.located_between = _('%s and %s', all_previous_activable_line[-1].name, all_next_activable_line[0].name)
            else:
                rec.located_between = _('No activable line before or after this one')
        else:
            rec.located_between = ''
        # code for rec_name field
        if rec.name:
            rec.rec_name = rec.name
        else:
            line_type_string = dict(rec._fields['line_type']._description_selection(self.env)).get(rec.line_type)
            rec.rec_name = _('%s between %s', line_type_string, rec.located_between)

